# How to input automatically in BATch file on DOS?

Tags: command-line, batch, ms-dos

I want to run a command that prompt for an argument, can I do a BATch file that run this command and then wait for a sec and "write" or "type" automatically (like a live person) the argument? Thanks.

Comment: Not with built-in commands. You would need a third-party program to send the keys to the console.

Comment: I highly recommend Autoit! for this sort of task. Actually what I highly recommend is to find a non-sendkeys way to do what you need to do but to use Autoit! if you have no other option.

Comment: Do you truly mean MS-DOS, as opposed to (say) Win32?  Or are you making the common mistake of [conflating textual user interface and operating system](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/a-cli-is-not-a-dos-prompt.html)?  If the latter, what operating system do you _really_ mean?  What operating system does your (unnamed, prompting for input) command natively run on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the command reads from stdin:

```
echo some text| command

(echo some text& echo line two) | command
```

If the command reads from the console specifically -- you cannot.

Answer (score 2):

The CHOICE command gives you the ability to set a default option after a specified time out:

```
CHOICE [/C choices] [/N] [/CS] [/T timeout /D choice] [/M text]

Description:
    This tool allows users to select one item from a list
    of choices and returns the index of the selected choice.

Parameter List:
   /C    choices       Specifies the list of choices to be created.
                       Default list is "YN".

   /N                  Hides the list of choices in the prompt.
                       The message before the prompt is displayed
                       and the choices are still enabled.

   /CS                 Enables case-sensitive choices to be selected.
                       By default, the utility is case-insensitive.

   /T    timeout       The number of seconds to pause before a default
                       choice is made. Acceptable values are from 0 to
                       9999. If 0 is specified, there will be no pause
                       and the default choice is selected.

   /D    choice        Specifies the default choice after nnnn seconds.
                       Character must be in the set of choices specified
                       by /C option and must also specify nnnn with /T.

   /M    text          Specifies the message to be displayed before
                       the prompt. If not specified, the utility
                       displays only a prompt.

   /?                  Displays this help message.

   NOTE:
   The ERRORLEVEL environment variable is set to the index of the
   key that was selected from the set of choices. The first choice
   listed returns a value of 1, the second a value of 2, and so on.
   If the user presses a key that is not a valid choice, the tool
   sounds a warning beep. If tool detects an error condition,
   it returns an ERRORLEVEL value of 255. If the user presses
   CTRL+BREAK or CTRL+C, the tool returns an ERRORLEVEL value
   of 0. When you use ERRORLEVEL parameters in a batch program, list
   them in decreasing order.

Examples:
   CHOICE /?
   CHOICE /C YNC /M "Press Y for Yes, N for No or C for Cancel."
   CHOICE /T 10 /C ync /CS /D y
   CHOICE /C ab /M "Select a for option 1 and b for option 2."
   CHOICE /C ab /N /M "Select a for option 1 and b for option 2."
```

So, in this case, you could just type something like `CHOICE /T 10 /C ync /D y /M "Do you wish to proceed [yes]?"`, and after 10 seconds, it would simply choose Yes for you.

Comment: Thanks. There is any way to type a word?

Comment: Unfortunately no, choice only gives you the options there, with the default to be a single letter/number of your choice.

Comment: there are other scripting environments out there, like .NET, autoIT, autoHotkey, that may be of benefit to you; unless you can provide more detail, it's difficult to fully answer this question.

Comment: You've got the wrong end of the stick.  The questioner doesn't want to prompt for input xyrself.  Xe wants to _programmatically respond to_ a prompt for input in an existing program.

Comment: @JdeBP, my apologizes, but that wasn't how i understood the question.  Thanks tho.

Comment: I mis-read it at first, too, and was about the construct a similar answer, or point to where [that question _must_ have been asked and answered before](http://superuser.com/search?q=choice.com&submit=search), when I said to myself "Hold on a minute!…".